# Passing strings between windows forms , without using .Show() method [without refreshing the form]

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 forms.

On form1 there is a textbox called textbox1 and a button [and many other textboxes as well]

On clicking the button , a new form , form2 opens

form 2 has a datagridview with 2 columns.

On clicking the datagridview cell [present in form2]
Using :

`private void dataGridView_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)`
 , 
The contents of the first column of the selected row must go to the textbox1 in form1 , without refreshing or reopening form1 .

How do I do that without using the .show() method as it would refresh my form1 and as a result lose all the user-typed info in the other textboxes?

**Note**: *retrieval from datagridview to string form is done by:*

```
dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString()
```

Comment: Either pass an instance of Form1 to Form2 to be able to modify Form1's controls directly, or make events in Form2 which Form1 subscribes to and updates the controls when the events are raised.

Comment: Should the second form close after selecting the value? It seems you are goring to create a lookup form to select a value from a list.

Comment: @VisualVincent I am a new programmer and a slow one too. I did not understand what you meant...sorry..

Comment: @reza That is exactly what I want

Comment: My first suggestion was that you pass a variable to Form2 when opening it, where you set the variable to Form1 like: `myNewForm2.Form1Instance = this;` (`this` is Form1 if you open Form2 from there). -- My second suggestion was to create an event. An example of an event is `Button1_Click` when you click a button called `Button1`. You even have an event in your question: `dataGridView_CellMouseClick`. You can read about creating events on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).

Comment: oh , I have done that.When I make an event , the data does pass but it reopens the first form[with the passed data] which is not what I want. I even tried making an instance in the constructor and I get the same result ;of the form reopening

Comment: Nevermind , I solved it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put that cell value in a `public property` like

```
public string gridcellValue
{
  get; set;
}
```

In your `dataGridView_CellMouseClick(` event handler set the property saying

```
this.gridcellValue = dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

Then in your form1 you can access it using the instance of form2 (since you created the form2 instance from form1)

```
textbox1.Text = frm2.gridcellValue;
```

Another approach is make that textbox a public property and pass the form1 instance in form2 constructor and set the textbox like

In Form1

```
public TextBox Form1Text
{
  get {return this.testbox1;} 
  set {this.testbox1 = value;}
}

Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this);
frm2.Show();
```

In Form2

```
public class Form2 : Form
{
  Form _form1;
public Form2(Form1 frm)
{
  _form1 = frm;
}

//In event handler

private void dataGridView_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
   //set the value
   ((TextBox)_form1.Form1Text).Text = dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
}
}
```

Comment: Neither of them seem to work. The first one does not transfer the value to the textbox. The 2nd one is using .show() method , which is what I dont want to begin with

Comment: And I did not mention on purpose that I am not using a regular textbox but an alphablend textbox from bob bradley. when I tried out your option 2 , the line `set {this.testbox1 = value;}` shows error under value , of cannot implicitly convert type Sys...forms.textbox to Zbobb.AlphablendTextbox. why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it and I think my answer could help someone in need[like I was]

Basically , in Form1 , you create a public static string ,like

`public static string mystring = "";`

then on the button which leads you to Form2 , do the following:

`private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {`

```
       Form2 frm = new Form2();

        if (frm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.txt_box.Text = Form1.mystring;

        }
    }
```

`

In form2,:

`

```
private void dataGridView_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Form1.mystring = dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            this.Close();


        }
```

And that is it!
good luck